# How install Apache Hadoop Client in Karaf

Tags: maven, hadoop, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I have tried to install apache hadoop client using feature xml approach mensioned in Apache Karaf Cookbook. But I'm not able instal using feature xml.Able to add feature repo in karaf but not able to install bundle the described in feature xml.

```
 Error executing command: Can't install feature hdfs2/0.0.0:
Could not start bundle mvn:org.apache.cxf/cxf-core/3.0.0 in feature(s) cxf-core-3.0.0: Uses constraint violation. Unable to r
esolve bundle revision org.apache.cxf.cxf-core [86.0] because it is exposed to package 'org.codehaus.stax2' from bundle revis
ions stax2-api [79.0] and stax2-api [67.0] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.apache.cxf.cxf-core [86.0]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.codehaus.stax2)(version>=3.1.0)(!(version>=4.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.codehaus.stax2
  stax2-api [79.0]

Chain 2:
  org.apache.cxf.cxf-core [86.0]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.ctc.wstx.stax)(version>=4.3.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=com.ctc.wstx.stax; uses:=org.codehaus.stax2
  woodstox-core-asl [80.0]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.codehaus.stax2)(version>=3.1.4))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package=org.codehaus.stax2
  stax2-api [67.0]
```

feature.xml is

```
<!DOCTYPE features>
<features name="sample-${project.version}">
    <repository>mvn:org.apache.cxf.karaf/apache-cxf/3.0.0/xml/features</repository>
    <feature name='xml-specs-api' version='${project.version}'
        resolver='(obr)' start-level='10'>
        <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.specs/org.apache.servicemix.specs.activation-api-1.1/</bundle>
        <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.specs/org.apache.servicemix.specs.stax-api-1.0/</bundle>
        <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.specs/org.apache.servicemix.specs.jaxb-api-2.2/</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.codehaus.woodstox/stax2-api/</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.codehaus.woodstox/woodstox-core-asl/</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxb-impl/</bundle>
    </feature>
    <feature name='hdfs2' version='${project.version}' resolver='(obr)'
        start-level='50'>
        <feature>xml-specs-api</feature>
        <feature>cxf-jaxrs</feature>
        <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6</bundle>
        <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:com.google.guava/guava/16.0.1</bundle>
        <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java/</bundle>
        <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.guice/</bundle>
        <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jsch/</bundle>
        <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.paranamer/</bundle>
        <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.avro/1.7.3_1</bundle>
        <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-compress/</bundle>
            <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-math3/3.1.1</bundle>
            <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2</bundle>
            <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:commons-configuration/commons-configuration/</bundle>
                <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-httpclient/</bundle>
                <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:io.netty/netty/3.9.2.Final</bundle>
                <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.12</bundle>
                <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.12</bundle>
                <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.9.12</bundle>
                <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-xc/1.9.12</bundle>
                <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.snappy-java</bundle>
                <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:commons-codec/commons-codec/</bundle>
                <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1</bundle>
                <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:commons-io/commons-io/</bundle>
                <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:commons-net/commons-net</bundle>
                <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.apache.zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.8</bundle>
                <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlenc/0.52_1</bundle>
                <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xerces/</bundle>
                <bundle dependency='true'>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.xmlresolver/</bundle>
                <bundle>mvn:org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.hadoop-client/</bundle>
    </feature>
</features>
```

Pom.xm(a part of it)

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
  <properties>
        <cxf.version>2.7.11</cxf.version>
        <camel.version>2.15.2</camel.version>
        <jms.version>3.0.4</jms.version>
        <cellar.version>3.0.3</cellar.version>
        <activemq.version>5.12.0</activemq.version>
        <http.version>3.0.4</http.version>
        <pax-http.version>3.2.3</pax-http.version>
        <pax-jetty.version>8.1.17.v20150415</pax-jetty.version>
        <spring.version>3.2.11.RELEASE_1</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>filter</id>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-artifacts</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifacts>
                                <artifact>
                                    <file>target/classes/features.xml</file>
                                    <type>xml</type>
                                    <classifier>features</classifier>
                                </artifact>
                            </artifacts>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>validate</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
                        <artifactId>features-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${cxf.karaf.version}</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <file>${project.build.directory}/classes/features.xml</file>
                            <karafConfig>${project.build.directory}/classes/bundles.properties</karafConfig>
                            <jreVersion>jre-1.6</jreVersion>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>validate</id>
                                <phase>process-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>validate</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

Comment: which version of Karaf are you using? 3.x or 4.0.x?

Comment: Karaf 3.x version.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your features.xml file as below.

mvn:org.codehaus.woodstox/stax2-api/3.1.4